# JavaFX HBox Alignment

Tags: java, javafx, alignment, vbox, hbox

I've been working on a software using JavaFX and I have a stupid but worrying problem.

In certain part of the code I have a `HBox`, and, inside of it three items: an `image`, a `label` and a `VBox`.

The issue is that I would like to have the `image` aligned to the left, that is, next to the left margin of the `window`, and the `VBox` aligned to the right, that is, next to the right border of the `window` and I don't know how to do it.

I've tried to use `VBox.setAlignment(Pos.RIGHT_CENTER)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show us your attempted code.

Comment: Intuition would say that the HBox simply orders them in the order you add them to the HBox through `hbox.getChildren().addall( arg0, arg1, ... argk);`

Answer (score 60):

This is a most common alignment issue when you want to place an item towards the two corners of the Layout.

Let us say you want to have :

```
HBox
  |
  ImageView (Left)
  Label (Center)
  VBox (Right)
```

I very simple solution is to use two extra `Regions`. One in between ImageView & Label. The other in between Label and VBox.

```
HBox
  |
  ImageView (Left)
  Region
  Label (Center)
  Region
  VBox (Right)
```

These Regions must have **`HGrow`** set as **`Priority.Always`**, so that if you resize the HBox, these two will grow, keeping the other elements intact in their location.

**FXML example** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="140.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="http://www.imaginaformacion.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/JavaFx.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="Label On the Center" />
      <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <VBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Label Inside the VBox" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Please note the `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"` in both the Regions.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Had a similar issue using `<VBox>` containing an ImageView. My controls were jumping up and down between image changes, using `<Region VBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>` solved my issue. :)

Comment: Thanks. I used the same logic, as :
`Region filler = new Region();
HBox.setHgrow(filler, Priority.ALWAYS);` then `hbox.getChildren().addAll(left, filler, right);`

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to save sometime

Answer (score 11):

I think that the best option could be switching from `HBox` to `BorderPane`. It let You make items sticked to any edge of Your window.
Another option is `GridPane`. You can select column and change its 'Halignment' property to 'RIGHT'.

And, by the way, I recommend using [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html) while having fun with JavaFX.

Comment: yea, that seems better

Comment: @torina, I'm glad I could help. Thanks. ;)