# Placing buttons on opposite sides of an adjustable window in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have two buttons that I'd like to use in my display screen: a reset button, and a settings button.

The problem is, I want them on opposite sides of the window (reset in the top right corner and settings in the top left) while being the same height. When I expand the window, however, the buttons stay in the same place, but I want them to move with the window walls.

I first tried using `setAlignment` of my reset button to `Pos.*TOP_RIGHT*` and the settings button to top left, but it comes out with the settings button being on top of the reset button.

```
    resetButton = new Button("Reset Gameboard");this.setTop(resetButton);

    resetBox = new HBox(resetButton);
    resetBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    backButton = new Button("Back to Settings");
    this.setTop(backButton);

    backBox = new HBox(backButton);
    backBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    resetbackBox = new HBox(backButton, resetButton);
    

    this.setTop(resetbackBox);`
```

[image: The reset button is below the settings button]

I currently am using (below) which during the initial window appears to be working and correctly spaced, but as soon as you expand the window the reset button doesn't follow it, although the settings button does.
`resetButton = new Button("Reset Gameboard");
this.setTop(resetButton);

```
    resetBox = new HBox(resetButton);
    resetBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    backButton = new Button("Back to Settings");
    this.setTop(backButton);

    backBox = new HBox(backButton);
    backBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    resetbackBox = new HBox(backButton, resetButton);
    resetbackBox.setSpacing(380);

    this.setTop(resetbackBox);`
```

[image: Without expanding the window, buttons look to be properly spaced]

[image: However, when expanded, only the settings button follows the window border]

Comment: Don’t use an `HBox`. Either use a `BorderPane`, with the buttons in the left and right, or an `AnchorPane` with the left anchor of one button set to zero and the right anchor of the other button set to zero.

Comment: You can also place a [spacer pane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834057/1155209) in the center of the HBox and set HGrow on it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem start from this line:

`resetbackBox.setSpacing(380);`

You have setted a fixed spacing value. To fix that you can easily add a component to HBox called [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html), this component allow to set a grow area between two buttons:

```
Button resetButton = new Button("Reset Gameboard");
Button backButton = new Button("Back to Settings");

Region region = new Region();
HBox.setHgrow(region, Priority.ALWAYS);

HBox topHBox = new HBox(backButton, region, resetButton);

this.setTop(resetbackBox);
```